# Is there a way to merge two arrays into one single array in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, merge

I'm kinda new in MongoDB and I'm having trouble to achieve a certain task. I'll try to explain it.

Here is my collection:

```js
'workers': [
    {
        _id: ObjectId(...),
        name: 'John',
        skills: [
            { id: ObjectId('111'), value: 2 },
            { id: ObjectId('222'), value: 3 },
            { id: ObjectId('333'), value: 4 },
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId(...),
        name: 'Mary',
        skills: [
            { id: ObjectId('222'), value: 5 },
            { id: ObjectId('333'), value: 2 },
            { id: ObjectId('444'), value: 3 },
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```js
result: [
    allSkills: [
        { id: ObjectId('111'), value: 2 },
        { id: ObjectId('222'), value: 5 },
        { id: ObjectId('333'), value: 4 },
        { id: ObjectId('444'), value: 3 }
    ]
]
```

My result should be a single array with all skills inside the `workers` collection (eventually I'll filter them).

In the example, I show my final result, with only unique values and the greater `value` for each skill, but what I'm trying to achieve here is just **merge all `skills` arrays into a single `allSkills` array**. For now, what I'm getting is a list of documents, each with its `skills` array.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
db.collection.distinct('skills');
```

[distinct api docs here!](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)

also, if you want to get only a prop of the skill object, like for example "value", you can do this:

```
db.collection.distinct('skills.value');
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Yep, it helps :)

I'm trying to develop this answer to achieve my final result, but definitely, it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I accepted Sebastián Espinosa's answer since it answered my question. But just for the record, I ended up using another solution and I'm putting here to future reference:

```js
db.workers.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$skills" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$skills.id',
            value: { $max: '$skills.value' }
        }
    }
])
```

Which produced the result:

```js
result: [
    { id: ObjectId('111'), value: 2 },
    { id: ObjectId('222'), value: 5 },
    { id: ObjectId('333'), value: 4 },
    { id: ObjectId('444'), value: 3 }
]
```

The treasure here lies on the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator, which helped to actually merge the `skills` arrays.

The reason I didn't use the marked answer was because I couldn't develop it to the final result I was looking for, but, as I said, it totally answered my original question.